# Как удалить подстроку максимальной длины, начинающуюся и заканчивающуюся заданными символами?

Tags: java, строки, подстрока

Есть задача, где входной текст разбивается на предложения, предложения на слова и др. В конце нужно собрать тот же текст воедино, но выполнив некоторые задачи.

Итак, есть `String sentence;`. Надо удалить подстроку из слова, начинающуюся и заканчивающуюся заданными символами, например, "а" и "б". Удалить только в слове с максимальной длиной подстроки.

Сам я разбил предложение на слова в цикле, искал слова, которые содержат "а" и "б" и выбирал из них самое длинное, где и удалял подстроку. Однако, слово может быть длиннее, а подстрока короче.

Как это сделать лучше?

**Пример:** есть предложение `а+б_а++б_+а+++б+_++а++++б++`, где `+` любой символ, а `_` это пробел. В нашем случае должна удалиться подстрока от `а` до `б` в последнем слове (т.к. она самая длинная) и останется такое предложение: `а+б_а++б_+а+++б+_++аб++`.

Comment: а вы сами пробывали что-то реализовать?

Comment: На словах объясню. берешь текст, делишь его на подстроки ( пробел как разделяющий символ), далее проверяешь уже подстроки в цикле, проверяешь так: первый символ == 'a', и последний == 'б' . если да, то выводишь... Но данный вопрос следует закрыть

Comment: Под подстрокой вы имеете ввиду слова?

Comment: @Санаев а с чего вы взяли что "а" должен быть первым, а "б" последним? Сам я реализовал таким образом, что подстрока удаляется в самом длинном слове. Но я понял, что не факт, что подстрока самая длинная, если слово самое длинное.. Например слово "аюбююююююююю" длинее, чем "аююбю". Но во втором слове подстрока от "а" до "б" будет длинее и в этом вся сложность

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov подстрока, как я понимаю - это любое кол-во символов строки

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин Стоп, то есть слово, это не "подстрока"? А можете тогда привести примеры работы программы (тестовые случаи как должно работатить) и желательно ваши наработки где результат есть, но он не такой, какой хотелось бы.

Comment: в таком случае делаешь так: ищешь первое вхождение буквы а, после этого ищешь первое вхождение буквы б . и удаляешь.

Comment: @Санаев было бы просто очень, если так. Но надо удалить самую длинную подстроку во всём предложении и только её

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин ищешь первое вхождение буквы а и последнее вхождение буквы б

Comment: @Санаев и что мне это даст?

Comment: опишу на словах. разбиваешь текст на подстроки ( пробел разделитель), далее по циклу пробегаешь по всем подстрокам и и ищешь в них первое вхождение требуемой первой буквы и с конца первое вхождение требуемой второй буквы. считаешь размер подстроки. запоминаешь индекс максимальной подстроки. и после цикла удаляешь эту строку... все очень просто!!!

Comment: Котаны, попрошу вас уважительно относиться друг к другу в беседе ^_^

Comment: Я бы использовал регулярные выражения для такой задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для простоты задачи предположним, что слова разделены только пробельными символами (имеются ввиду любые пробелы в Unicode).

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String text = "а+б а++б +а+++б+ ++а++++б++";

    // паттерн означает строку, которая содержит один или более непробельных символов "\\S+"
    // перед которыми подстрока "а" (франгмент (?<=а) — это так называемый positive lookbehind),
    // после которых подстрока "б" (франгмент (?=б) — это так называемый positive lookahead).
    String regexPattern = "(?<=а)\\S+(?=б)";

    // получаем объект для итерации по всем совпадениям
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regexPattern).matcher(text);

    // для хранения максимульной длины совпадения
    int maxLength = 0;
    // для хранения индексов самого длинного совпадения
    int startIndex = -1;
    int endIndex = -1;

    // итерируемся по всем совпадениям
    while (matcher.find()) {

      int length = matcher.end() - matcher.start();
      // если совпадение самое длинное, то сохраняем его индексы
      if (length > maxLength) {
        startIndex = matcher.start();
        endIndex = matcher.end();
      }
    }

    // если совпадение найдено (оно будет самым длинным), то вырезаем его
    if (startIndex > 0)
      text = text.substring(0, startIndex) + text.substring(endIndex);

    System.out.println(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: "разделены только пробельными символами" - вы имеете ввиду, в "ссс, ддд"  "ссс," будет словом? Но вроде это не влияет на решение в целом.

Comment: @0xdb Я не знаю, что является разделителем. Может там слова могут идти через запятые без пробелов или ещё какие-то условия есть.

Comment: Ну да, по условию "+" любой символ кроме пробела, т.е. "аххх,хххб" попадание, как и ожидалось. Если так, то ваша фраза скорее всего лишняя. Зачем "предположим ...", если в вопросе это же самое уже "предположили".

Comment: @0xdb Не все люди умеют предусматривать сразу все случаи, поэтому я написал это.

Comment: Согласен, если что, топикастер уточнит. (+)

Answer (score 2):

Если я верно понял задачу, то надо найти максимальную подстроку в слове (слова разделены пробелами), которая начинается на 'а', заканчивается на 'б', причем внутри этой подстроки нет ни а, ни б и удалить все символы между началои подстроки и концом. Если так, то это можно за линейное время сварганить

```
string RemoveSubString(string str, char start, char end)
{
    int s = -1;
    int e = -1;     
    int pointer = 0;

    while(pointer < str.Length)
    {   
        while(pointer < str.Length && str[pointer]!=start && str[pointer]!=' ') pointer++;  

        if (pointer < str.Length && str[pointer]==start)
        {           
            int s1 = pointer;           
            pointer++;
            while(pointer < str.Length && str[pointer]!=end && str[pointer]!=' ') pointer++;

            if (pointer < str.Length && str[pointer] == end)
            {
                int e1 = pointer;               

                if(s == -1 || (e-s) < (e1-s1))
                {
                    s=s1;
                    e=e1;
                }                               
            }   else pointer++;     
        } else pointer++;
    }   

    if ((e-s) < 2) return str;  
    return str.Substring(0, s+1) + str.Substring(e, str.Length-e);
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("а+б а++б +а+++б+ ++а++++б++", 'а', 'б'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("а+б_а++б_+а+++б+_++а++++б++", 'а', 'б'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("1-----2-------2--------2", '1', '2'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("12", '1', '2'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("21", '1', '2'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("2-1-2", '1', '2'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("1-2", '1', '2'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("1222222", '1', '2'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("2111111", '1', '2'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("1-111111", '1', '1'));
Console.WriteLine(RemoveSubString("1-11111--1", '1', '1'));
```

Вывод

```
а+б а++б +а+++б+ ++аб++
а+б_а++б_+а+++б+_++аб++
12-------2--------2
12
21
2-12
12
1222222
2111111
1111111
1-111111
```